# A hint for a simple question about cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Somebody can to give me a hint in the following question?

> Let $X$ be an infinite set. Show that $X$ has the same cardinality that $X \cup \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The most likely answer required by your lecturer is the answer given below by Asaf.  Alternatively, you could note that the cardinality of Q is the least infinite cardinal, then use cardinal arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $X$ is infinite we can write it as $X'\cup Y$ where $X'\cap Y=\varnothing$ and $|Y|=|\Bbb N|$. Since $|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}|$, we can use this to find a bijection between $Y$ and $Y\cup\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me!